# When to use get property and inline function for TypeScript properties

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple component class as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ControlService } from '../services/control-service';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: './control-bar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./control-bar.component.less']
    })
    export class ControlBarComponent {
        get context(): any { return this.controls.context; }
        constructor(private controls: ControlService) { }
        is(contextName) {
            return this.context.constructor.name == contextName;
        }
    }
```

The problem arises when I try to write a unit test for the given code. I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
>       at ControlBarComponent../ src / app / courses / control
>       - bar.component.ts.ControlBarComponent.is(http://localhost:9876/
>       _karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/courses/control-bar.component.ts:12:33)
>       at Object.eval[as updateDirectives]
>        (ng:///DynamicTestModule/ControlBarComponent.ngfactory.js:111:25)

After playing around tod and trying find an answer I try the following code which no longer throws an error.

```
// Same except for the following line 
context = () => this.controls.context;
// replaces 
get context(): any { return this.controls.context; }
```

So are there any drawbacks to this solution? And if so, when should I use these two code constructs?

Comment: I think that's workaround solution what you need here is create mock ControlService and pass when you get the instance of component

Comment: what is the `provider` section in your spec file ? Share the code of spec files. The  error is caused by `this.context.constructor.name` line as `this.context` is not defined